# Separate 2D curve offset as new curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there away to save the offset of a 2D curve as a new curve? I've tried to achieve the same result with curve > transform > push/pull, but this didn't give the results I needed, because the offset wasn't constant. The geometry offset works perfect, but I really need it as a separate curve. Does anybody know a solution?

[image]

Comment: Check out the shipped add-on Curve Tools > 'Outline', and possibly other features.. just learning it, myself.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Enable shipped add-on Curve Tools. Sidebar > 'Outline' > Offset curve

Answer provided by: @Robin Betts

Comment: Glad it's good for you. The add-on is still in development, but already looks useful. You can accept (tick)  your own answer, to mark it as solved.. :)